# JS: read out the given SRC-attribute from the current image (nivo slider)

Tags: javascript, click, nivo-slider

I am kind of unused to javascript.

I would like to read out the given SRC-attribute from the current image (nivo slider).
By clicking, the `href` should be opened.

```
$('a', vars.controlNavEl).bind('click', function(){    
    window.location = "xxx currentImage.attr('href')";  //something like that?
});
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a bit unclear.

`window.location` redirects to the specified resource, in your case, to the image resource specified through src attribute. If you want stay in the actual page but shown the image like a pop-up or something like you can use jQuery for that or Bootstrap. I don't know if Nivo Slider provides that functionality.

Comment: Thanks! I want to use this nav-button like a menu. No new window, no popup. It should redirect to the sub-page which is written in the href-Tag of the currently shown picture in Nivo-Slider. Hope this clarifies, what I want?

Comment: EDIT: Ah, damn. My bad!! There is no "href" attribute in the image-tag of course. I want to read out the <a>-link in my html-code. Think, this is kind of complicated...

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `window.location` you will redirect the user from the current page to another page
2. Your code is wrong, your assign to `window.location` a string instead of the reference to the image `SRC` attribute.

This is the correct code (if you want redirect)

```
window.location.href = currentImage.attr('src');
```

if you want to open a new window, you should check the `window.open` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Unfortunately it didn't work for me.

To clarify my question:

I want the code to work as a usual link. No new window. The click on the nav-button (in Nivo-Slider) shall not show the specified image, but work as a menu-button to open another sub-page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I just saw, that I went wrong. There is of course no "href" specified in the image's tag.

So what I did to solve my problem is: adding a href-attribute to my images like this:

```
<a class="imgTip1" href="soft-about.html"><img src="images/index-sliders2/soft.jpg" data-thumb="images/nivo-menu/soft.png" alt="" href="soft-about.html" title=""></a>
```

And the javascript looks like this now:

```
    $('a', vars.controlNavEl).bind('click', function(){  // NEW
            window.location = vars.currentImage.attr('href'); 
    });
```

That works for me so far.

**Is this a problem for any browser or whatever? Adding a "href"-attribute to the image's tag in html?**

Comment: For HTML5 actually you can define any extra custom attribute that you want prefixed with `data-` (e.g. `data-href="index.html"`) and with that you ensure actual browsers can access to the custom attribute. Maybe with `href` works in some browsers, but others can ignore the custom tag.